# iOS get current location using GPS device

Tags: ios, gps, location

I want to use CLLocationManager to get the current user location using GPS antenna, not the cellular network. How can I ensure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choices is either the standard location service (e.g. `startUpdatingLocation`, for which you can specify the `desiredAccuracy`), or the low-power significant change service (e.g., `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`). But you generally don't specify location services based upon hardware, but rather on the basis of your app's functional needs. Use the standard service if you need an accurate location, and try using the significant change service if you don't need the same level of precision.

See the [Location Awareness Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1) for more information.

Comment: Also dont forget to add `gps` to the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in the Info.plist!

Comment: Setting desiredAccuracy lower than 100 m will assure that it not only relies on cellular data.

Comment: thank you, but I want to know the accuracy and the distance filter of the low-power significant change service (i.e if I use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges how much it's accurate and what is the distance of the significant change)??

Comment: I'll see if I can get a few data points, but I think it's very rough, maybe as much as a few km off. I use it for retrieving local weather, so that's fine. And it's quick (just a second or so), which is the beauty of it. But you certainly can't use it for street level navigation or stuff like that. I inferred from your question that you need a degree of accuracy afforded only by the standard location services.

Comment: @AhmedSaid Driving around today, I found that the significant location service varied from a just few meters off to up to 0.7km off of the location that the more accurate location service ended up determining. I'm in a fairly built up area with good cell coverage, so I wouldn't be surprised if the significant change service might be even more off in other areas with less comprehensive cell coverage.