# Xcode - How to get location accuracy data?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, geolocation, location, core-location

I am building an iOS app which is now able to get the current user location and display to its user (using CLLocationManager). Is there a way to also display the location accuracy?

Thanks!

Comment: look at once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323373/ios-get-current-location-using-gps-device

Comment: http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `CLLocationManagerDelegate`:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
   CLLocationAccuracy accuracy = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;
}
```